# How can I enable and disable WiFi connectivity with a jailbroken iOS device?

Tags: ios, wifi, jailbreak

How can I programmatically enable and disable WiFi connectivity with a jailbroken iOS device?

Answer (score 1):

```
void SetWiFiMode(BOOL mode)
{
    void* manager = WiFiManagerClientCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, nil);
    if (mode)
    {
        WiFiManagerClientSetProperty(manager, CFSTR("AllowEnable"), kCFBooleanTrue);
    }
    else
    {
        WiFiManagerClientSetProperty(manager, CFSTR("AllowEnable"), kCFBooleanFalse);
    }
    CFRelease(manager);
}
```

To use this your application entitlements should have `com.apple.wifi.manager-access` key with boolean value set to true. All functions can be found in private MobileWiFi.framework

Comment: hey bro, could you tell me how to use this code ?. can you teach me

Answer (score -2):

There isn't a way using the APIs provided by the SDK. It's trivial to do if you use private frameworks, but if you use private frameworks, you will be in violation of Apple's SDK license agreement.

Comment: I know that. but my app only run on jailbroken iOS devices.not uploaded in app store.