# Wifi Enable/Disable on Jailbreak iOS devices

Tags: ios, xcode, wifi, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

I know that there are private frameworks available on GitHub. So far I have tried:

- https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks
  This does not work: runtime I get error: 
  **Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBApplicationController", referenced from:**. Also, sometime it gives Error for ARC. (like ARC forbids to use object in structure and all that).
  I think it lakes its implementation files.
- https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers 

  iOS Runtime Headers (on github). This contains many frameworks but still getting error:
  **ld: in 'Win ipad/iOS-Runtime-Headers-master/lib/libdispatch.dylib', can't map file, errno=22 for architecture i386
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Isn't there any simple sample application out there where I can just have single usage of such a framework? (I have found a one:  **SOLStumbler**, which is good, but does not detect the wifi networks on my jailbroken device. I also tried putting **Apple80211SetPower** and tried to enable/disable the wifi, but it crashes with the annoying error: **EXEC_BAD_ACCESS**.

I really need some guidance since I have stuck here for many days and didn't find any concrete solution. Please help.

Comment: did you install all necassarry tools from cydia for compiling jailbreak apps? i think i remember that you have to install a few libs...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661518/how-can-i-enable-and-disable-wifi-connectivity-with-a-jailbroken-ios-device/16463604#16463604

Comment: creker can you plz explain which other necessary tools required? cz first time i am doing work on jailbreak device things..