# Enable/Disable Wifi on Jailbroken Device in iOS7

Tags: ios7, wifi, jailbreak, cydia

I am looking for a specific set of function calls into the iOS7 private frameworks / dylibs etc to enable/disable WiFi programmatically on a device running iOS7, or alternatively some other workaround to do the same.  If you are tempted to mark this question as a duplicate, please reference a question (an answer would also be nice!) that refers to iOS7. This would have to be a question asked after September, 2013, when iOS7 was released. The private framework class that did this in iOS6, SBWiFiManager, no longer exist in iOS7.  I've read through many StackOverflow questions and answers, and grep'd through a lot of framework header files already, so I am aware of some of the ways to go about figuring this out.

*** EDIT ***

It turns out this is still the correct answer, also has reference to the necessary framework:
[How can I enable and disable WiFi connectivity with a jailbroken iOS device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661518/how-can-i-enable-and-disable-wifi-connectivity-with-a-jailbroken-ios-device)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I enable and disable WiFi connectivity with a jailbroken iOS device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661518/how-can-i-enable-and-disable-wifi-connectivity-with-a-jailbroken-ios-device)

Comment: Your question is duplicate. It doesn't matter how old the answer as long as it solves the problem. Code in my answer still works.

Comment: "this doesn't prevent the device from connecting again in the future" it does prevent your device from connecting to the forgotten network. That's the whole point of "Forget this Network". iOS doesn't automatically connect to WiFi network it doesn't know.

Comment: @creker you are right. I guess I'll make a few excuses. I was thrown by the disappearance of the SBWiFiManager.h header file in iOS-7, although it turns out that class also still exists. I also overlooked/missed that MobileWiFi.framework in my search/grep.  Excuse 2: Seems like Forget this Network does work correctly now. In some previous iOS versions, it didn't - there was a documented tweak whereby AT&T phones would give preference to attwifi networks (since changed/fixed), which may be the source of my confusion. I agree with the votes to close.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about that "feature".